# Print unsigned char array to hex

Tags: c++, hex, unsigned-char

**The problem**
I've got some byte buffer, that get's filled during runtime. I want to display the buffer's content, using hex-code. So this is the definition of the buffer:

```
enum { max_data_length = 8192 }; //8KB
unsigned char stream_data_[max_data_length];
```

Now I wanted to print the content. The data is stored for example like this:

```
stream_data_[0] = 124;
stream_data_[1] = 198;
stream_data_[2] = 60;
```

Now I want to print the contents of this buffer (in hex). I tried several stack overflow posts but they all use unsigned int or fill the arrays. I am really stuck on this problem!

**The code**
I tried for example:

```
enum { max_data_length = 3 }; //8KB
unsigned char stream_data_[max_data_length];
stream_data_[0] = 20;
stream_data_[1] = 30;
stream_data_[2] = 40;
char str[16];
sprintf(str, "%X02 ", stream_data_);
std::cout << str;
```

But I can't understand why the result is always different, each time I run it.
For example:

```
C2CA426002
7C92553002
```

Comment: So what did you try, how does your printing code look?

Comment: I meant that you should include the code in the question, and also tell us what it generated, and why you're not happy with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only issue is that iostream treats `unsigned char` as a character type,
rather than as a small integer.  To get around this, just cast your `unsigned
char` to `unsigned` before outputting it.  (For the rest: you'll have to
specify hex output, and possibly the width and fill characters, of course.)

To dump an array of `unsigned char`:

```
void
dumpArray( unsigned char const* array, int count, std::ostream& dest )
{
    dest.setf( std::ios_base::hex, std::ios_base::basefield );
    dest.fill( '0' );
    while ( count > 0 ) {
        dest << std::setw( 2 ) << static_cast<unsigned>( *array );
        -- count;
        if ( count != 0 ) {
            dest << ' ';
        }
    }
}
```

(Of course, in production code, you'll want to save the previous formatting,
and restore it before returning.)